# Re-named assembly, application won't build

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I renamed my WPF application's assembly from DBce_TEST2 to AMS, then attempted to build it to see what would happen. I ran it, and it wouldn't build for obvious reasons but now after renaming it back to DBce_TEST2 I get the following error:

```
Managed Debugging Assistant 'BindingFailure' has detected a problem in 'G:\C# Projects\Asset Management System\DBce_TEST2\bin\Debug\DBce_TEST2.vshost.exe'.

Additional Information: The assembly with display name 'AMS' failed to load in the 'Load' binding context of the AppDomain with ID 1. The cause of the failure was: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'AMS' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Renamed the assembly again to some random text, attempted to run it, then renamed back to original assembly name and the error disappeared. Guess some generated files were messed up by visual studio a little bit, and this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The error can be fishy. Use Fusion log viewer to understand what has gone wrong.

[How to enable assembly bind failure logging (Fusion) in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net)